# Guidance needed on HTML and Javascript for my practicelabtest

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
Dear <span id="salutation">Name</span>;

<p>

  It has come to our attention that your invoice <span id="invoice">ID</span>

  has yet to be paid. It has now been <span id="time">some time</span> since

  you received <span id="item">the material</span> from Evil Incorporated. Please

  remit payment immediately. <span id="threaten"></span>

</p>

  Yours sincerely,<br>

<br>

<br>

  J. Smith, Accounting

<div id="buttons">
```

I have a practice labtest in 2 days and were having somethings thats going to be very similar to it. Given the code above I have to answer the question and the question goes as.

> a) Write a function reverse(tag) that takes one string as argument(tag).
>   tag is the id of an elements in HTML. This function  should reverse
>   the innerHTML value associated with the id provided. if the element
>   does not exist in the HTML document then your program should display
>   and alert and do nothing. Test your code by defining the format()
>   function to call reverse ('salutation').
>
> b) write a function clearit() that adds a button "print" to the
>   id='buttons'.  This print should display it as print, and should have
>   onclick  attribute that refers to a function print()
>
> c) write a function print() that displays and alert with the text "print
>   called' to demonstrate that the code above works properly.

I have the first part I believe:

```
function reverse(tag) {
  var el = document.getElementById(tag);
  if(!el) {
    return alert('nope');
  }
  el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.split('').reverse().join('');
}
```

But im not sure how to approach the b) and c)... Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: For (a) you should still write the format function.

Answer (score 0):

For b), you should be adding a new element to the DOM, in this case, a print button. You can read the documentation on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp) for examples on how to do it.

As for c), I think the instructions are more than enough to get you started. But for more reading, check out their [page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) on onclick events :)

Good luck!